# как правильно работать со стейтом в реакте при фильтрации списка задач

Tags: javascript, reactjs

всем привет! изучаю реакт, только начал, поэтому прошу не судить строго. Собственно проблема вот в чем, делаю простой список задач todoApp, и нужно сделать фильтрацию задач на активные, выполненные и все задачи.

есть стейт в главном, родительском компоненте :

```
export default class App extends Component {

constructor (props) {
  super(props)

this.state = {
  tasks : [ {value : 'Walk', active : true, editing: false, id : 1},
            {value : 'Talk', active : true, editing: false, id : 2},
            {value : 'Move', active : true, editing: false, id : 3}
          ]
  }
}`
```

и вот ф-я которая фильтрует выполненные задачки и меняет стейт, я так понимаю, проблема в самом стейте, в том как я его меняю, так как даже скопировав стейт в новый массив я все равно меняю старый стейт и в нем после фильтрации остаются только выполненные задачки, активные удаляются и как итог, когда я переключаю фильтр на активные задачки, то стейт оказывается пустым и список задач тупо оказывается пустым.. что я делаю не так ?

```
  showCompletedTasks = () => {
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.tasks))
const filtered = copy.filter(el => !el.active )

this.setState((state) => {
  return {
    tasks : [...filtered]
  }
})
```

}

Comment: Создайте вторую переменую, в которую положите исходный массив, а результаты операции фильтрации присваивайте значению tasks. При изменениях самих тасков, надо будет в исходный массив передавать данные. По другому, к сожалению, никак.